# PHP AJAX - upload and crop

Tags: php, ajax, upload, crop

I found a script - Upload and Crop image on this website http://onlinewebapplication.com/2011/08/image-upload-cropping-php-jquery.html  Everything works fine, but I need to add my new name for new images...

When I upload an image -> before crop I can change file name, but it works only for big images, for thumb I don't have an idea because the variables are sent by AJAX.

My version works here - [link](http://bodyartcenter.pl/cropimages/)
first input is for file path, second for new filename..

I need change name for big image and thumb, but it works only for big.
How send variable "image_name" to ajax_image.php ?

Anyone ? Please help me, I need this ..Thanks

Comment: The thumbs are generated as `"small" . $username . ".jpg"`. what do you want to change?

Comment: I want change $username to variable from form

Comment: Firebug works well if you want to see what gets submitted by your AJAX script :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name for the big image in this line:

```
$actual_image_name = time().substr($txt, 5).".".$ext;
```

and for the small image you can pass the name as parameter by changing this:

```
url:"ajax_image.php?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="...etc
```

to this:

```
url:"ajax_image.php?sname=blabla&t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="...etc
```

also for the small image again change in ajax_image.php this:

```
$new_name = "small".$session_id.".jpg"; // Thumbnail image name
```

to this:

```
$new_name = "smallqa".$_GET['sname'].".jpg"; // Thumbnail image name
```